# jinja2 - create href with variable from loop

Tags: html, jinja2

I'm try to create a dynamic href for a website

I've tried this:
(where "gruppe" is a list of servers)

```
{%- for item in groups[gruppe] %}
  {% set url = 'https://cmk.abc.local/abc/check_mk/view.py?host=' + {{ hostvars[item]['openstack']['name'] }} + '&site=abc&view_name=host' %}
  <a href="{{ url }}"> {{ hostvars[item]['openstack']['name'] }}.abc.local</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Expected result should be:

```
https://cmk.abc.local/abc/check_mk/view.py?host=server01&site=abc&view_name=host#
```

Does anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It's tough to say without knowing the shape of the data. If you can post what "groups" looks like (as JSON) that would be helpful.

The first thing that stands out to me is "gruppe". Is that supposed to be a key in the `groups` object or is that supposed to be dynamic?

Try:

```
{%- for item in groups["gruppe"] %}
...
```